# Can the quality of an accent attempt be quantified?

Tags: accent

I have seen videos that interview accent experts, like on [why Americans do bad English accents](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DZF3RiMFInI&pp=ygUVYWNjZW50IGV4cGVydCBicml0aXNo) (a reason given is a lack of exposure). But are there something like references that one could point to to rate accents? I would think at least one should survey native speakers to get a rating (I met a Kiwi who said he would get mistaken for British by Americans even). Maybe AI could do ratings nowadays if trained on enough. I figure one would need to do individual ratings for each case, even if a reference existed, like having to break down examples, showing where they messed up. If ratings were compiled somewhere that'd be easier though. Like something one could use to show how bad Americans doing accents in lotr were, except like wormtongue, which one may figure influenced having less in the hobbit.

Comment: Where would you start with objectively trying to rate an accent?

Comment: That's literally what I'm asking

Comment: It is more that its **quality** can be assessed. Speech coaches will do such things and tell the student where they are failing and succeeding. This is more helpful than saying "Your British English accent is 71%" -- It is possible to invent an arbitrary scale, though what use it would have is questionable.

Comment: As KillingTime implies, opinions of what's 'good' may vary; it's impossible to be objective. Your last sentence doesn't make sense to me, but I don't remember any accents in 'LOTR' being spectacularly bad.

Comment: There could be points they are getting right or wrong. Those could be counted. Or with a survey, on a scale from 1 to 10, certain people will fall in different points. Or how is quality assessed precisely? It's just expert opinion? What do they use?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around: "which one may figure influenced having less in the hobbit." Maybe it's just too early…

Comment: Anyways saying there is no way to quantify them is an answer.

Comment: A survey wouldn't need to ask for ratings directly. It could just ask people if they guess the person is a native speaker or not, for those that don't know. Then a person could get a percentage that said yes.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many British and American accents there are? Possibly hundreds.

Comment: That would have to be taken into account yeah. I didn't say simple would be a requirement.

Comment: Most Americans just sound like "normal" TV accent these days anyways. At least from what I've seen. Maybe there's a study on that.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here, as it's not really a question about English language, grammar, history, etc. It might be slightly more on-topic in language learning SE, as language teachers may have ways to rate the quality of accents. Or possibly even on Movies and TV SE.

Comment: This is not about english language learners, nor is it restricted to film media, those were just examples.

Comment: I spent a month in California, and almost daily someone would say "Hey, you're Australian!" I have a fairly strong Yorkshire accent. Not sure how anyone could ever confuse the two… but they did.

Comment: That could be the flipside, how to quantify how well people hear accents, vs how well they say them. Or this would need to be taken into account when determining quality also.

Comment: @user14094230 That's not true, regional accents are still going strong. I live in the Boston area and lots of locals have Boston accents (think Matt Damon). Southern accents are even more prevalent, I think.

Comment: Probably the best way to quantify this is how surprised viewers are when they see a foreign actor who has been playing an American on a talk show. Several of the leads on The Walking Dead are British (Andrew Lincoln, Lauren Cohen), but you'd never know it as a viewer.

Comment: @alphabet True, he has the South Boston accent, like on the SNL sketches.

Comment: OIC now. Well, we only have so many Chuckys to go around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to quantify this numerically, you might try looking at [formant frequencies (see Wiki).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant) These are a way of measuring the quality of a vowel  in an objective acoustic manner. By comparing the formant frequencies (and their relative positions) between two speakers, you could plausibly determine how similar their accents are; through some sort of clustering analysis you might be able to determine how close someone's pronunciation of different vowel phonemes are to those of (say) General American or contemporary RP.

Of course, it's all more complicated than that for a multitude of reasons. First, which vowel phonemes occur in which words also varies between accents, as with the *lot-cloth* split in AmE or the *trap-bath* split in BrE. Secondly, you'd also need to take into account allophony, since the same phoneme can be realized by different phones in different contexts, as with æ-tensing and Canadian raising. Thirdly, none of this takes into account differences in consonants, which of course are also quite important.